# How to format legend using scale_color_discrete in stacked plot and have thousand separators included in the y-axis r

Tags: r, ggplot2, separator

I have this dataset to work with to format legend and include thousand separator on the y-axis;

```
Data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Site,    ~Test,    ~Score1,      ~Score2,       ~Score3,
  "A",   "SD",  5904,    9691,    NA, 
  "B",   "SD",   2697,    4484,    NA,
  "A ",   "MB",  11418,    7666,      NA,
  "B",   "MB", 2517,    6445,    NA,
  "C",   "FO",  NA,    NA,    9588,
  "C",   "FI", NA,    NA,    5423,
  "C",   "NF",  NA,    NA,    1527
)
```

I used this code;

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 library(ggplot2)

 Data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Site,Test)) %>%
   mutate(Test = factor(Test,
                           levels = c('SD','MB','FI','FO','NF'),
                           ordered = T)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=Site,y=value,fill=name, legend = TRUE))+
   ylim(0,20000) +
   ylab("Total score") +
   geom_bar(stat='identity')+
   facet_wrap(.~Test, scales = 'free_x', ncol = 5, strip.position = "bottom")+
   theme_minimal()+
   theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
         panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
         strip.background = element_blank(),
         strip.background.y = element_blank(),
         panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         panel.border = element_blank(), 
         strip.text       = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9))+
   scale_color_discrete(name = "Legend",label=c("Score 1","Score 2","Score 3"))
```

I am failing to have my legend properly labeled and thousand separator on my y-values.

Comment: How do you want the legend to be? Do you want the keys to be rearranged? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only changes you have to do are:

1. `ylim(0, 20000)` for `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format())`
2. `scale_color_discrete()` for `scale_fill_discrete()`.

```
Data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Site,Test)) %>%
  mutate(Test = factor(Test,
                       levels = c('SD','MB','FI','FO','NF'),
                       ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Site, y = value, fill = name, legend = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format()) +
  ylab("Total score") +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Test, scales = 'free_x', ncol = 5, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
        panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Legend", label = c("Score 1", "Score 2", "Score 3"))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To get your legend with the correct name, change your `scale_color_discrete` to `scale_fill_discrete`. You are mapping to the fill aesthetic and not the color aesthetic.

To get your y labels, you can add `scale_y_continuous` with some parameters. You can assemble the labels to look like you want.

```
Data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Site,Test)) %>%
  mutate(Test = factor(Test,
                       levels = c('SD','MB','FI','FO','NF'),
                       ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Site,y=value,fill=name, legend = TRUE))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  facet_wrap(.~Test, scales = 'free_x', ncol = 5, strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
        panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        strip.text       = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Legend", label=c("Score 1","Score 2","Score 3")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Total Score", 
                     limits = c(0, 20000),  
                     breaks = seq(0, 20000, 5000), 
                     labels = c(0, paste(seq(5000, 20000, 5000)/1000, "000", sep = ",")))
```

[image]